# Form not displayed correctly

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

i have a form consists of the following models

Employee.rb

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base

      attr_accessible :employee_number, :joining_date, :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name,
      :gender, :job_title, :employee_department_id, :qualification, :experience_detail,
      :experience_year, :experience_month, :status_description, :date_of_birth, :marital_status,
      :children_count, :father_name, :mother_name, :husband_name, :blood_group, :nationality_id,
      :home_address_line1, :home_address_line2, :home_city, :home_state, :home_pin_code,
      :office_address_line1, :office_address_line2, :office_city, :office_state, :office_pin_code,
      :office_phone1, :office_phone2, :mobile_phone, :home_phone, :email, :fax, :user_id,
      :reporting_manager_id, :employee_grade_id, :office_country_id,
      :home_country_id, :employee_category, :employee_position_id

      belongs_to :employee_department

      has_many :counselor_supervisors
      belongs_to :employee_position

      def to_label
       full_name = first_name + " " + last_name
      end

    end
```

EmployeeDepartment.rb

```
class EmployeeDepartment < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :code, :name

      has_many :employees

      has_many :employee_positions

      has_many :counselor_supervisors

      has_many :batch_leadership_supervisors

    def to_label
      name
    end


    end
```

CounselorSupervisor.rb

```
class CounselorSupervisor < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :employee_id, :employee_department_id, :employee_position_id
      belongs_to :employee
      belongs_to :employee_department
      has_many :batch_counselor_supervisors

    def to_label
     employee.to_label
    end

    end
```

BatchCounselorSupervisor.rb

```
class BatchCounselorSupervisor < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :counselor_supervisor_id , :employee_department_id , :counselor_batch_id, 
    :batch_counselor_advisors_attributes
  has_many :batch_counselor_advisors
  belongs_to :counselor_supervisor
  belongs_to :employee_department
  belongs_to :counselor_batch

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :batch_counselor_advisors

end
```

Employee_position.rb

```
class EmployeePosition < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :position_title, :employee_department_id

  has_many :employees
  belongs_to :employee_department

  def to_label
    position_title
  end
end
```

batch_counselor_supervisors/new.html.erb (part of the form which related to my question)

```
              <%= simple_form_for(@batch_counselor_supervisor) do |f| %>
              <%= f.error_messages %>
            <%= f.association :employee_department, as: :select %>
              <%= f.input :counselor_supervisor_id , collection: EmployeeDepartment.all, as: :grouped_select, group_method: :counselor_supervisors %>
<% end %>
```

the dropdown list appears like this:

[image]

If I added an employee which belongs to the first department `"Business Administration"`, the form will be displayed correctly like this:

[image]

Update: after adding `label_method: :to_label`, so my form became like this :

```
 <%= simple_form_for(@batch_counselor_supervisor) do |f| %>
              <%= f.error_messages %>
            <%= f.association :employee_department, as: :select %>
              <%= f.input :counselor_supervisor_id ,
               collection: EmployeeDepartment.all, as: :grouped_select, group_method: :counselor_supervisors, label_method: :to_label %>
    <% end %>
```

the employee name displayed correctly but still the department name not displayed correctly as the following image:

[image]

Is this `SQLite3` issue ? and What can I do in order to solve this if it sqlite3 issue or not.

Comment: check what sql query is running in the console

Comment: @SabyasachiGhosh i don't understand how this will help me ? also in the beginning of my question i have queries when i try them on console   the query with the first department only has the right result

Comment: no My question is please check the actual sql query running in the background once.

Comment: @SabyasachiGhosh i think , in the second image where the list is displayed correctly when i have employee belongs to the first department the Employee model is loaded in console , but in the first image when i have an employee belongs to any other department but not the first department the Employee model is not loaded, what can i do then ?

Comment: and what about the queries ? why only query with the first department have a right result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, you only have an issue with the labels not being displayed correctly. Could you try to explicitly set the method on your input:

```
label_method: :to_label
```

For more information have a look at https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form and search for *label_method*

Comment: after adding `label_method: :to_label`, this made the employee name displayed correctly , but the department name still not displayed correctly, and i have updated my question.

Comment: solved by adding this also `group_label_method: :to_label` , please add this to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What are the actual relevant rows in your **Employee** table and your **EmployeePosition** table?

In your **Employee** table you happen to have these 2 columns;
**employee_position_id** 
**employee_position**.

Since **employee_position** is also a table name, it's bad/reduntant model structure which might be confusing your include method of the query.  It's possible that in your tables, the rows are fully filled out to complete the first query, but not for any of your other queries even though you think it is.

Comment: oh sorry , employee_position in Employee model is not used , just forget to delete it , but the problem is still there

Comment: Can you please provide your EmployeePosition.rb file as well?  And did you check the actual rows just in case?

Also, Rails has some implied syntax methodology involving variable/method names and their plural forms.  I would recommend using "position_name" for the actual name of the position instead of "employee_position" because that could also be the problem.

Comment: question updated with `employee_position.rb` , and i have changed to `position_title` instead of `employee_position` and the problem still exist

Comment: Don't forget to update your queries to accommodate the name change you just made.  If you did, also remember to change the queries you posted in the question so other people can still help you too.

Comment: i dropped my db and re-created it again with the new changes and updated the queries in my question

Comment: what could cause this issue ? :(

Comment: Are you ABSOLUTELY POSITIVE the data in the database/tables is filled in enough to return the result you are expecting?  Because it doesn't look to me like there is a problem with your Queries, and you haven't said anything about the contents of your tables.